# How can I use strtok in PHP?

Tags: php, strtok

Please can you explain to me why I get this result?

```
echo strtok('../../../its-2016-03/2016-11-15/c_00.01-rend.xml#eba_tC_00.01','-rend');
```

Result:

```
../../../its
```

It is pretty weird that I get this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

> strtok() splits a string (str) into smaller strings (tokens), with each token being delimited by **any** character from token.

Since you pass `'-rend'` as `token`, `strtok` returns your string up to the first character in the string which is also in `token`, in this case `-` and so the return value is `'../../../its'`.

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, perhaps you want

```
echo explode('-rend', '../../../its-2016-03/2016-11-15/c_00.01-rend.xml#eba_tC_00.01')[0];
```

which will yield

```
../../../its-2016-03/2016-11-15/c_00.01
```